# Unhandled Exception, Access violation reading location

Tags: c#, .net, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I use third party libary in my forms application with C# Visual Studio 2013 and I take fingerprints with a fingerprint scanner.
While taking fingerprints my application throw unhandled exeption. What can be reason of this error?

This is error:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x693B0A37 (msvcr100.dll) in
>   GetFingerprints.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0E762000."

And here is the error which shows in event viewer.

> Faulting application name: GetFingerprints.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x542bcc4c Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version:
>   10.0.40219.325, time stamp: 0x4df2be1e Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x00010a37 Faulting process id: 0x1094 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cfdd5c12b8ea77 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Proje\MyProject\bin\Debug\GetFingerprints.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll Report Id:
>   fdc362c7-494f-11e4-9a0a-f0921cdc1fd5

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using for that? It can be helpful to reproduce the issue and provide a fix.

Comment: I cannot find the spesific code block for this, i think that methots avaiable in third party dlls.